# Integrating map in ios 8.0

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-api-3, ios8

I have integrated google map API in my android app. now i am programming same in iOS. I am not understanding how to integrate google map API in to my iOS 8.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user Default MapKit from iOS, with the nice tutorial [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial)

You can use different way provided by Google Map SDK, with standard example  [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/).

Hope this help you to do better.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the MapKit framework.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/

It's pretty easy to use and you can find lot of tutorials on Google.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html